# How to launch games in Dolphin: "Failed to create Vulkan surface." and "Failed to initialize video backend!"

Tags: debian, kde, games, emulation, vulkan

In Debian11/KDE with Wayland I can't launch games anymore with the Dolphin emulator. Created a bug report with some more details [here](https://bugs.dolphin-emu.org/issues/13086).

Don't know if that's due to building a newer version of Dolphin than the version with which launching games worked on this machine, or due to switching from X11 to Wayland. However, because for a while launching games with Dolphin still worked on it [but with Lutris it didn't](https://github.com/lutris/lutris/issues/4030), I think it must be due to a newer version of Dolphin. If there's an easy way to install the version from the Debian repos without parallel to the built version, I'd try if it works with that version.

I installed `mesa-vulkan-drivers` and then in Dolphin changed "OpenGL" to "Vulkan" in Options->Graphics Settings->Backend. When I try to launch a ROM game that used to work before, I get an error message saying `Failed to create Vulkan surface.` and when I close it also `Failed to initialize video backend!`. If I have OpenGL set as backend I only get the second error. I don't have a graphics card but the game was working fine with the same hardware earlier. I'm using i915 graphics drivers. The only output in the console is: `MESA-INTEL: warning: Performance support disabled, consider sysctl dev.i915.perf_stream_paranoid=0`.

Has anybody solved this issue or a suggestion what I should try?